# How to know when a Listview is finished with populating data in android?

Tags: android, android-listview

I am using an array adapter to populate the listview items. Is there any event listener that can be relied on to know when the listview is updated with new data?

Comment: I think the answer is "No, there is no", but could I ask you why do you need such an event?

Comment: I want to start animation on a container having listview after the contents are completely rendered.If rendering is not completed, the animation does not have the right effect.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just set a flag to trigger an event when the listview is completely rendered?
 Then create your own Event handler to start your animation when the flag is set.

Comment: Is there any function like onRenderingComplete() in ListView?

Comment: @SemperDiscens  And how would you do that?

Comment: That's the question he's asking isn't it? What is the flag?